# HBase Mapper with multiple rows as output

Tags: hbase

I have a Mapper that I want to run in HBase (0.90.4; Hadoop 0.20) which will produce several (1000 - 10000) new Rows of data in a different HBase table for each single input row.

I started with a `TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>` that I assume, in the map function, I would call `context.write(someSingleOutputRowPut)` 1000 times to push the data to the output table.

Would I be better off having a read-only mapper and doing a manual write to my output table with batches of Lists of Puts? Or should I change the output type of the mapper to be List? Or is it fine to call context.write a bunch of times like that?

Edit : starting to gather some data on the "naive" approach of calling context.write thousands of times and it doesn't look good so far (now that I'm trying larger data sets, particularly) so time to try random things and see what improves it.

Comment: I don't follow how a table reducer would help.

Answer (score 0):

Using context.write(...) or using table.put(...) is essentially the same.

You should turn off the auto flush to have the batching effect while writing your data. Make sure to have a flush performed at the end of your mapper phase to avoid losing any piece of data.

It sounds like you don't need a reducer phase and you should keep it that way as it will improve your performance by avoiding the shuffle, sort and data transfer phases.

Comment: In an hbase table mapper, you don't have direct access to the underlying table, just the context - I don't see where I would mess with the auto flush settings. I think that context must be doing some kind of batching under the hood but I wonder if it is flushing commits at the end of the whole map task, not at the close of a given map invocation. You are correct that I am skipping the reducer.

Comment: My point is not use the context.write function so your mapper won't write anything out but internal to your mapper, you use table.put(...). On HTable, there is a method setAutoFlush(boolean). Set it to false and it will batch for you. You have to call close on the HTable at the end such that it flushes the buffer properly. If you get an exception, you should fail the whole map task.